# Push forward of measures and weak* converence

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

I have to prove the following:

> **Proposition**:
>   Let $$\mu := \mathcal{L}^1 \big|_{[0,1]} $$
>   and $1<p< \infty$. Consider the sequence of functions $ \{f_h \}_{h>0} \subset L^p(\mathbb{R}, \mu)$ where $f_h(x)=f(hx)$ with
>   $$ f(x) := \begin{cases} 1 \quad & \text{ if } \quad 0 \le \{x\} < \frac{1}{2} \\ -1 \quad &\text{ if } \quad \frac{1}{2} \le \{x\} < 1 \end{cases}$$
>   where $\{x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$. Let $\nu:= \frac{1}{2} ( \delta_1 + \delta_{-1})$. Then
>
> 1. For each $h>0$ it holds
>      $$ ((f_h)_{\#}) (\mu) = \nu $$
> 2. $f_h \overset{\ast}{\rightharpoonup} 0$ as $h \to 0$
>
> where $((f_h)_{\#}) (\mu)(B) = \mu ( f_h^{-1}(B))$ for any borel set $B$.

I'm not sure they are true; I suspect it should be $h>1$ and $h \to + \infty$. Indeed:

1. $ ((f_h)_{\#}) (\mu) = \nu  \Leftrightarrow \mu ( f_h^{-1}((a,b))= \nu((a,b))$ for every $-\infty< a <b <+ \infty$. If both (or none of) $1$ and $-1$ belong to $(a,b)$ the equality is easy. Suppose $1 \in (a,b)$ and $-1 \notin (a,b)$, and take for example $h=1/2$ then
   $$\nu((a,b))= \frac{1}{2} $$
   and
   $$ \mu (f_{1/2}^{-1}((a,b))) = \mu (\{ x \in [0,1] \mid f_{1/2}(x) = 1 \})  = \mu ( \{x \in [0,1] \mid 0 \le \{ \frac{1}{2} x \} < 1/2 \} ) = 1$$
   On the other hand, if $h \ge 1$ I think the equality holds. Am I wrong?
2. If $h < 1/2$ and $\varphi \in L^q(\mathbb{R}, \mu)$ with $1/p + 1/q =1$ then

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_h \varphi d \mu = \int_{ \{ x \in [0,1] \mid 0 \le \{ hx \} < 1/2 \} } \varphi d \mathcal{L}^1 = \int_{[0,1]} \varphi d \mathcal{L}^1 = \int_{[0,1]} \varphi d \mu  $$
and then I have  $f_h \overset{\ast}{\rightharpoonup} 1$ as $h \to 0$. I think I can prove that, if $h \to + \infty$, the set on which $f_h = 1$ becomes union of smaller and smaller disjoint intervals which total measure is always 1/2. The same for the set on which $f_h = -1$. But, even if it is true, I don't know how to prove statement 2 (with $h \to + \infty$).

Comment: Yes for 1 you need $h\in\mathbb N$

Comment: Thank you. What do you think about the second part of the "proposition"?

Comment: Yes for 2 you need $h\to\infty$ to conclude $f_h\rightharpoonup 0$

Comment: Otherwise you have $f_h(x)\to\mathrm{sign}(x)$ if $h\to0$.

Comment: I'll try to work out the details for $h \to +\infty$. By now, I can't see how to prove it. If $h \to 0$ don't you think I'll get 1, being the support of the measure $[0,1]$?

Comment: Oh yes, in [0,1] you converge to $1$. On the entire real line, $f_h$ converges pointwise to $\mathrm{sign}(x)$